# How to make this gradient with a nois pattern?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, noise

I have this gradient on my toolbox and I want to replicate this in Photoshop or Illustrator (or any free software).
[image: gradient I want to have]
In photoshop I tried to put a normal black an gradient in front of a green layer and added speckle option to the gradient. 
[image: here is my result]
Do you know a better way to achieve this special gradient because I am not happy with my result.

Comment: What part of the result are you not happy with?

Comment: I cant put a filter on the layer. I think the noise is to sharp so I wanted to put a gaußscher filter on it but it had no effect.

Comment: Make the layer a Smart Object and then apply the filter.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with what you have done. It's exactly how I would suggest you do it. As for the sharpness of the noise layer - it would seem you have it as a smart object. You should be able to apply a guassian blur filter to it - there is no reason why you can't. Just select it, and apply the filter.

Comment: But I don't have any options with this speckle option (eg. rougher or finer). I there any alternative to this effect?

Comment: Applying a filter to what you have already done is by far the simplest method to get it looking like your example picture or at least very close. To tell you the truth, there's probably close to a bazillion different ways to do it. Do you want simple or as accurate as possible?

Comment: I don't mind. I would like to have **some** other alternatives

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following you correctly, I believe what you're trying to do can be done as follows:

** Note:Turning your gradient layer into a smart object, then adding a Gaussian Blur filter to it will allow you to non-destructively adjust the look of the gradient.

I realize this isn't what you're looking for (stay with me here) – but it does still have its purpose. **

1. Highlight both your green (teal - sorry OCD) layer and your gradient layer in the Layers Panel:

[image: Highlighted layers]

2. Right-click and convert the two layers together into a single Smart Object:

[image: Layers Panel context menu]

3. Now you can apply your Gaussian Blur as a Smart Filter in order to realize your desired result:

[image: Gaussian blur applied]

---

Note: The "speckle option" is known in English as the Dissolve Blend Mode, applied in the Layers Panel (just for anyone else trying to find this option).